# Is there a way i can use np.array in the code

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I wanted to know if there is a way i can covert this code into a np.array code. then add it to [link](http://textuploader.com/702i). I wanted to add an angle where the ball launches from.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
from scipy.integrate import ode
import matplotlib.pylab as pl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
from matplotlib import*
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
from __future__ import division
import math

 def projectile_xy(initPos,g,initVel):
    data_xy = []
    initTime = 0.0
    while True:
```

now calculate the height y

```
        y = initPos + (initTime * initVel * math.sin(theta)) - (g * initTime * initTime)/2
```

projectile has hit ground level

```
        if y < 0:
            break
```

calculate the distance x

```
        x = initVel * math.cos(theta) * initTime
```

append the (x, y) tuple to the list

```
        data_xy.append((x, y))
```

use the time in increments of 0.1 seconds

```
        initTime += 0.1
    return data_xy

g = 9.8
#h = float(raw_input("Enter the height "))
initPos = float(raw_input("Enter the height "))
der = float(raw_input("Enter the angle "))
#v = float(raw_input("Enter velocity ")) 
initVel = float(raw_input("Enter velocity ")) 


theta = math.radians(der)  # radians
data_der = projectile_xy(initPos,g,initVel)
```

find maximum height ...

```
point_height_max = max(data_der, key = lambda q: q[1])
xm, ym = point_height_max
x_max = max(data_der)[0]

print('''
Projectile Motion ...
Using a firing angle of {} degrees
and a muzzle velocity of {} meters/second
the maximum height is {:0.1f} meters
at a distance of {:0.1f} meters'''.format(der, initVel, ym, xm))
print "maximum distance" ,(x_max)
```

Enter the height 1
Enter the angle 45
Enter velocity 30

```
Projectile Motion ...
Using a firing angle of 45.0 degrees
and a muzzle velocity of 30.0 meters/second
the maximum height is 24.0 meters
at a distance of 46.7 meters
maximum distance 91.2167747731
```

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this approach:

```
import numpy as np

linear_vel = 20
ang = np.pi/3
y=10
x=12
g=9.8
y_vel =  linear_vel*np.cos(ang)
x_vel =  linear_vel*np.sin(ang)


t = (y_vel+np.sqrt(y_vel**2+2*g*y))/g   #time when projectile hits               ground
n= 20 #number of instances of time you want

time_values = np.linspace(0,int(t),n)
axes = np.zeros((2,n))

for i in range(0,n):
    axes[0,i]=x_vel*time_values[i]
    axes[1,i]=y_vel*time_values[i]-0.5*g*time_values[i]**2



#print time_values
#print axes
```

Comment: You can use broadcasting: `axes[0] = x_vel * time_values` and `axes[1] = y_vel * time_values - 0.5 * g * time_values ** 2`  and get rid of the for loop, too.